# How to Write Letters With Symbols

Tags: c++, letter

[image: Like this one]

For now, I've only been able to write the letter K, how can I write a word that we can change its size with the letters "A, E, K, N, Z"?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    
    int i, j, n;
    
    printf("Please write size of the K letter (only odd numbers): ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    
    for(i=0; i < n/2; i++){
        printf("*");
        for(j=i; j < n/2 - 1; j++)
            printf("  ");
        printf("*\n");
    }
    
    printf("*\n");
    
    for(i=0; i < n/2; i++){
        printf("*");
        for(j=0; j < i; j++)
            printf("  ");
        printf("*\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "change its size"?

Comment: First refactor your code so you can say `printLetter('K', 2, 5)`, which would mean "print me the characters that make up line 2/5 of the letter K". Then, change your code to accept a word. Finally, loop over the lines and for each line call `printLetter` for every letter in turn.

Comment: Imagine a square grid. There are two cases: size is odd, size is even. Manually draw on paper how would each character look like for both cases. Once you are done and are sure, you can write the code.